Serialization issue in the passing an array in the CoreWCF service
I am working on migrating an old WebService from .NET (.asmx) to a CoreWCF SOAP service. The intention is to move from .NET Framework 4.0 to .NET 6/8 without affecting any upstream dependencies.
Mostly, the migration has been successful, but there is one use case that is failing. The old WebService has an API that accepts a string array as input. However, when I implemented the same parameters in CoreWCF, the incoming array is always received as empty.
The key difference I noticed is in the exported WSDL. The CoreWCF service specifies a namespace for the array element as “http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays,” whereas the older WebService did not have any specific namespace for that array element.
My primary suspicion is that CoreWCF is unable to deserialize the array due to the message inspectors I added I see these inspectors retrieve the values before they are passed to the operation. I also attempted to modify the request before sending it to the operation, but this approach is neither elegant nor effective.
I would greatly appreciate any guidance on resolving this issue.

I found a post with a similar issue to yours and has been resolved.  Migrate ASMX web method to WCF which accepts string array. In the meantime, I'd like to ask if you can provide the code for us to test?

Thanks this answers my question, exactly the thing I was looking for.

ASMX is obsolete since 2005 and didn't support the SOAP standards introduced back then. You're getting an error because WCF, not just CoreWCF, is far stricter about compliance. You'd get the same errors had you tried to migrate 19 years ago. The code was already obsolete in .NET Framework 4.0 and depended on legacy classes

Check the ASMX-to-WCF migration and ASMX Interoperability documentation. These documents describe several of the issues you'll encounter and how to handle them. The clients of the ASMX service expect it to behave the old way. There are several SO questions going back to 2008 as well, asking how to handle ArrayOfString.

You can create custom class like below (change the Namespace as per your need)
[CollectionDataContract(Name = "ArrayOfString", Namespace = "http://example.com/Report", ItemName = "string")]
   [Serializable]
   public class ArrayOfString : List<string>
   {
   }

